# How to get your program to download safely in chrome

Tags: html, download, web, warnings

I am a small programmer and on my website https://kovetstech.000webhostapp.com/products.html (on chrome) when i download stuff i made it gives me

the warning when you download says "Sun screen modes.exe is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous Discard"

and you can find the code for Sun screen modes: https://github.com/ShayVash/Smenu/blob/master/Smenu/Smenu/Form1.cs
is there anyway to disable it or make chrome trust the stuff i make?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix. Go to the icon that has 3 horizontal lines in the top right corner, right under the X -> go to stting near the bottom -> scroll down and click "show advanced setting" -> under the privacy section, uncheck the 5th box that says "enable fishing and malware protection". But this unfortunately is only changing your browser settings, so a user may get the same 'error' which you are referring to.

Comment: the problem is not that i cant download it i can. but how do i make it stop showing this warning from anyone downloading my products

Comment: You can't. .exe files are prevented to download by default due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

.exe is executible file extension so everytime you'll downlaod that will ask you for the same thing. You can select keep files anyway option at download.

Also for permenent solution look for Anna Jeanine answer

Happy downloading.